# Gap between content and border when using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row of images in a div with a flex display. They are intended to lie plush against a bottom border, but instead there is a gap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                height: 100px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: flex-end;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: aquamarine;
                border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);
            }
            img {
                width: 80px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="https://urnabios.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/angel_oak_tree.jpg">
            <img src="https://cdn.thecoolist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Japanese-Cherry-beautiful-tree.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the padding of the div is 0, and the border is defined in absolute pixels. So how is this happening, and how might the intended layout be obtained?

Comment: When I run the code snippet the images are flush against the bottom. There is a `border-bottom` though, in your CSS.

Comment: Yes, @Arkay stated that there was a `border-bottom`, but was trying to remove the gap between the images and the bottom border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the 'box-sizing' of the div to 'border-box' would solve the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                height: 100px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: flex-end;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: aquamarine;
                border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 87%);
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            img {
                width: 80px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="https://urnabios.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/angel_oak_tree.jpg">
            <img src="https://cdn.thecoolist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Japanese-Cherry-beautiful-tree.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read more on box-sizing [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score -1):

The html elements have a default style in case of body its

```
display: block;
margin: 8px;
```

More info here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

changing the margin to 0 should work

```
body {
margin:0px;
}
```